# How to match lambda to template parameter without specifying template params

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, template-argument-deduction

I'm writing a message receiving library and want to write a simple lambda to call when a message is received on a given endpoint.

When I try a simple lambda, it doesn't match the `std::function` template because the lambda is not the exact type, which makes sense.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <functional>
#include <memory>

const std::string endpoint1 = "ipc:///tmp/endpoint1.ipc";
const std::string endpoint2 = "ipc:///tmp/endpoint2.ipc";

class ISubscriber {
public:
    virtual ~ISubscriber() {};
};

template <typename T>
class Subscriber : public ISubscriber
{
public:
    Subscriber(const std::string & endpoint, std::function<void (const T&)> callback);
};

class Context
{
public:
    template <typename T>
    void addSubscriberListener(const std::string & endpoint, std::function<void(const T &)> callback)
    {
        // add to subscribers list
    }

private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<ISubscriber>> _subscribers;
    // All the other goo to make messaging work
};

class Type1 {};
class Type2 {};

void test()
{
    Context context;
#if 1   // Desired syntax
    context.addSubscriberListener(endpoint1, [] (const Type1 & t) {
    });
    context.addSubscriberListener(endpoint2, [] (const Type2 & t) {
    });
#else   // Undesired syntax
    context.addSubscriberListener(endpoint1, std::function<void(const Type1 &)>([] (const Type1 & t) {
    }));
    context.addSubscriberListener(endpoint2, std::function<void(const Type2 &)>([] (const Type2 & t) {
    }));
#endif 
}
```

The desired syntax gives me

```
Test.cpp: In function ‘void test()’:
Test.cpp:43:10: error: no matching function for call to ‘Context::addSubscriberListener(const string&, test()::<lambda(const Type1&)>)’
         });
          ^
Test.cpp:25:11: note: candidate: ‘template<class T> void Context::addSubscriberListener(const string&, std::function<void(const T&)>)’
      void addSubscriberListener(const std::string & endpoint, std::function<void(const T &)> callback)
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Test.cpp:25:11: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
Test.cpp:43:10: note:   ‘test()::<lambda(const Type1&)>’ is not derived from ‘std::function<void(const T&)>’
         });
          ^
Test.cpp:45:7: error: no matching function for call to ‘Context::addSubscriberListener(const string&, test()::<lambda(const Type2&)>)’
      });
       ^
Test.cpp:25:11: note: candidate: ‘template<class T> void Context::addSubscriberListener(const string&, std::function<void(const T&)>)’
      void addSubscriberListener(const std::string & endpoint, std::function<void(const T &)> callback)
           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
Test.cpp:25:11: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
Test.cpp:45:7: note:   ‘test()::<lambda(const Type2&)>’ is not derived from ‘std::function<void(const T&)>’
      });
```

It's not obvious to me if I need extra plumbing, or what that plumbing should be to make it work.

What are my options to get to the desired syntax?

Comment: You probably want [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), I think.

Comment: I'm curious how are you planning to invoke these subscribers if the interface only has a destructor?

Answer (score 4):

But you really need that `addSubscriberListener()` receive a `std::function` ?

What about simply accept a generic type `F` (for "functional") ?

```
template <typename F>
void addSubscriberListener (const std::string & endpoint, F callback)
{
    // add to subscribers list
}
```

This way you can go around your chicken-and-egg problem you have: the lambda can be converted to a `std::function` but isn't a `std::function` so the compiler must known the `T` type to convert the lambda to a `std::function` and deduct from it the `T` type.

Anyway... if you need to maintain the `std::function`... not exactly the desired syntax but... you could explicit the `T` type

```
// --------------------------VVVVVVV
context.addSubscriberListener<Type1>(endpoint1, [] (const Type1 & t) {
});
context.addSubscriberListener<Type2>(endpoint2, [] (const Type2 & t) {
});
// --------------------------^^^^^^^
```

It's another way to break the chicken-and-egg problem: you explicit the type `T`, so the compiler know that the lambda has to used to initialize a `std::function<void(Type1 const &)>` (fist call) and a `std::function<void(Type2 const &)>` (second call call).

**-- Edit --**

The OP precise that

> at some point, I need to declare a type of the lambda parameter to unpack into, then pass that into the lambda...

The OP also precise that can use C++17 so... what about deduce `T`, from `F`, using `std::function` deduction guides?

Given that your `callback` callable receive **only** an argument, you could write (sorry: code not tested)

```
template <typename F>
void addSubscriberListener (const std::string & endpoint, F callback)
{
  using T = std::remove_cv_t<
               std::remove_reference_t<
                  typename decltype(std::function{callback})::argument_type;

  // add to subscribers list
}
```

Unfortuntely `std::function::argument_type` is available only if the `std::function` receive **only** one argument and, furthermore, is deprecated in C++17 and removed from C++20.

So maybe you could write a custom type traits as follows

```
template <typename>
struct getTypeFirstArg;

template <typename R, typename T1, typename ... Ts>
struct getTypeFirstArg<std::function<R(T1, Ts...)>>
 { using type = T1; };
```

and extract `T` with

```
   using T = std::remove_cv_t<
                std::remove_reference_t<
                   typename getTypeFirstArg<decltype(std::function{f})>::type>>;
```

The following is a full compiling example

```
#include <functional>
#include <type_traits>

template <typename>
struct getTypeFirstArg;

template <typename R, typename T1, typename ... Ts>
struct getTypeFirstArg<std::function<R(T1, Ts...)>>
 { using type = T1; };

template <typename F>
void foo (F f)
 {
   using T = std::remove_cv_t<
                std::remove_reference_t<
                   typename getTypeFirstArg<decltype(std::function{f})>::type>>;

   static_assert( std::is_same_v<T, int> );
 }

int main ()
 {
   foo([&](int const &){});
 }
```

See also the answer from Guillaume Racicot that should works also in C++11 and C++14.

Comment: I think I do.. at some point, I need to declare a type of the lambda parameter to unpack into, then pass that into the lambda.. unless there's a way to keep F all the way through the chain, then get the argument type of F.

Comment: @bizaff - can you use C++17? In that case you can deduce the `T` type, from `F`, using (inside the method) `std::function` deduction guides. If you want, I can try to add an example. But only from C++17.

Comment: Yes I can.. I'd love to see it.

Comment: @bizaff - answer improved; hope this helps (but see also the answer from Guillaume Racicot for a pre-C++17 solution).

Answer (score 1):

You should skip the `std::function` and use the lambda directly:

```
template <typename F>
void addSubscriberListener(std::string const& endpoint, F callback)
{
    // add to subscribers list
}
```

This makes type deduction available for the lambda type

> at some point, I need to declare a type of the lambda parameter to unpack into, then pass that into the lambda..

So if I understand you need to reflect on the parameter type of the lambda?

That can be done using a similar pattern to boost::callable:

```
template<typename>
struct extract_arg_types {};

template<typename R, typename C, typename Arg>
struct extract_arg_types<R(C::*)(Arg) const> {
    using arg_type = Arg;
};
```

Then you can use that in your class:

```
template <typename F>
void addSubscriberListener(std::string const& endpoint, F callback)
{
    using T = typename extract_arg_types<decltype(&T::operator())>::arg_type;
    // add to subscribers list
}
```